# How to open a view top of a another view on the button click in react native?

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

How to open a view top of a another view on the button click in react native?  I tried use **redux** but i didn't find the right way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean "How to open a popup type screen on a button click"? 
If so, then you need to use Modal component.

Here's the link to the docs of modal component -

> https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/modal

Comment: Thanks for fast response, i have use the model and i change visibility of model  using redux state but it didn't work. any idea why?